# refactoring tests that use assert_raises

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I have a test block:

```
describe 'without' do

  describe 'author' do
    let(:author)  {nil}
    it('fails')   {assert_raises(ArgumentError) { excerpt }}
  end

  describe 'title' do
    # same content as above, but testing title
  end

  describe 'content' do
    # same content as above, but testing content
  end

end
```

This works fine and the tests pass - but since there's a lot of repetition here, I wanted to refactor:

```
describe 'without' do

  describe 'author' do
    let(:author)  {nil}
    it('fails')   {assert_failure(excerpt} # added a method in this line
  end

  describe 'title' do
    # same content as above, but testing title
  end

  describe 'content' do
    # same content as above, but testing content
  end

  # and the method here
  def assert_failure(instance)
    assert_raises(ArgumentError) { instance }
  end

end
```

However this doesn't work - my tests fail with the following error:

```
construction::without::author#test_0001_fails:
ArgumentError: Excerpt cannot be built: Author missing
```

Which is the error that I would expect to be raised with missing information - and is exactly what I'm testing.  So it seems that when this assertion is extracted, the `ArgumentError` is being raised and stopping the test before `assert_raises` can make any kind of comparison.  I looked into the [code](http://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_raises) for this assertion, but I can't make out why this would happen when the code is extracted into another method, but not when it's in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write with the following syntax:

```
assert_raises(ArgumentError) { excerpt }
```

What you are actually passing to `assert_raises` is a [*block*](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html). This means that the code (`excerpt`) is not evaluated until the method itself decides it wants to evaluate it.

With this syntax, though:

```
assert_failure(excerpt)
```

`excerpt` is evaluated *before* `assert_failure` starts.

If you want to duplicate the above behavior, you need to pass `assert_failure` a block:

```
def assert_failure(&block)
  assert_raises(ArgumentError, &block)
end

  describe 'author' do
    let(:author)  {nil}
    it('fails')   { assert_failure { excerpt } }
  end
```